# Across systems, How a process communicate with other process?

Tags: linux, process, system-calls, ipc, shared-memory

I have learnt below IPC mechanisms,

- BSD style half-duplex pipes
- SYSV style message queues
- SYSV style semaphore sets
- SYSV style shared memory segments
- BSD style sockets

---

---

**Half-duplex pipe** can be used as 1-1 process communication, one-way. Any connected process must share a related ancestory. `pipe()` allow communication between processes, **within a system**.

---

**Message queue**(linked list) can be used as 1-1 process communication, bi-directional between any two processes(`long mtype`) **within a system**. For every `msgsnd()` from one process creates an item in queue(linked list), corresponding `msgrcv()` from another process read/delete the queue item.

### [image]

---

**Shared memory** can be used as a many-many process communication, bi-directional, **within a system**. Internally, it is a mapping of an area (segment) of memory that will be mapped and shared by more than one process.

### [image]

---

BSD socket(`socket()`/`bind()`/`listen()`/`accept()`) can be used for many(*client*)-one(*server*) two-way communication **across systems with different OS**, **but** in a client-server mode.

---

Question:

1)

Across systems with similar OS, what is the IPC mechanism(provided by Linux) for many-many process communication, in **non client-server** mode?

2)

Across systems with different OS, what is the IPC mechanism(provided by Linux) for many-many process communication, in **non client-server** mode?

Comment: What is your definition of client server?

Comment: @icarus Client, I mean, a process **1)** placing `connect()` request on TCP/IP stack and `read()`/`write()` **2)**  talks directly to server(`struct sockaddr_in`) on UDP/IP stack and `sendto()/recvfrom()`. Server, I mean, a process, which `listen()`/`accept()` to requests from client

Answer (score 1):

Given your definitions I would go with files including named pipes in a shared filesystem. The 9p protocol in particular was designed to do this, where programs would export virtual filesystems a d react to events.

Not sure why you left named pipes off your original list.

Comment: If one process populate data thru named pipe, Can multiple processes get that data? or Can single process get that data?

Comment: @overexchange, No  - something reading a named pipe removes that data, just like a pipe created with `pipe()`

Comment: How does corba work? I think that is non client server model? Across different OS

Comment: corba is a much higher level, typically implemented on top of tcp sockets so by your definition is cliwnt-server.

Comment: Is there a client-server definition, other than I mentioned(above)?